# How to send GET request with raw body json - retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a web service with **GET** method and raw body json like this:

[image]

but my function show error:

```
@GET("/api/Sliders")
Call<SliderModel> Sliders(@Field("Page") String Page,
                          @Field("Count") String Count,
                          @Field("Cat") String Cat);
```

my error:

```
 @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
```

Comment: What error you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out and let me know if this works for you, a while ago I worked with custom verbs and this may be helpful.

```
interface ApiService {
    @HTTP(method = "GET", path = "/path", hasBody = true)
    fun get(body: RequestBody)
}
```

When calling your API pass RequestBody:

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("media-type"), "content")
```

[Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)

---

By the way, It's better to switch to a POST or Custom Verb. Using GET is not a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

**Follow this**

First Create a Java Class SliderModel.java

[image]

**after that do like this.**

[image]

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/api/Sliders")
    Call<SliderModel> getPosts();


}
```